# CSV in python getting wrong number of rows

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that I want to work with using python. For that I'm run this code :

```
import csv
import collections

col_values = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('list.csv', 'rU',) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)
    row_count =len(data)
    print(" Number of rows  ", row_count)
```

As a result I get **4357** but the file has only **2432** rows, I've tried to change the delimiter in the `reader()` function, it didn't change the result. 
So my question is, does anybody has an explanation why do I get this value ? 
thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

since the number of column is also too big , here is the output of  the last row and the start of non existing rows for one columns
 [image]

opening the file with excel the end looks like :

[image]

I hope it helps

Comment: Can you post, as an example, a couple of rows from your file?

Comment: Yes.. Please share some data. I executed code with 10 lines in csv file and   result came proper.

Comment: Read the csv.reader docs, and use `'r',newline=''` with `open`, assuming Python 3.

Comment: @MarkTolonen  didn't  solve the issue still getting 4357  rows !

Comment: Get a hex editor and see what is wrong with your file, or provide a link to a sample of it.

Answer (score 1):

try using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('list.csv')
df.count()
```

check whether you are getting proper rows now

Comment: I didn't want to use panda , because  it has a conflict with Tensorflow. But it's  a way to do this. I've  set a limit for numbers of row